Time conjunctions reported speech
My book says that we don't have to report sentences after time conjunctions like after, when, as long as even if they aren't true anymore. Examples


I'm happy as long as you work.


He said he was happy as long as you work.


He will come when he wants.


He said he would come when he wants.
What do you think do you agree with my book. I know I'm also able to report them but is it leaving without changes grammatically correct?

Some speakers would shift "work" to "worked" and "wants" to "wanted" while others would not.  That a fair number of speakers would not make that shift is the basis for saying it is not required.

Your sentences are very difficult to understand if you don't distinguish the words you are asking about by putting them in italics or quotation marks. Also, what is "my book"? Please give author/title.

OP has stated

My book says that we don't have to report sentences after time conjunctions like after, when, as long as even if they aren't true anymore

I understand that your book is advising you not to backshift tenses  after time conjunctions.
If we consider the reported speech of your example sentences :

First sentence:.
He said he was happy as long as you work.

Here the present tense "work" implies a general truth. We have shifted the main clause because the statement was made in the past but the clause after the time conjunction is still true so we didn't backshift.
Now let's consider the reported speech of the second sentence:

Second sentence:.
He said he would come when he wants.

Maybe this statement was made on a specific occasion.
In this case the reported speech would be:
He said he would come when he wanted.
So the rule for reporting the clause after the time conjunction is:
For clauses after time conjunctions (like "after", "when", etc.), you can either:.

Keep the original tense if the situation remains true or unchanged.
Backshift if the situation has changed or is no longer true.

Your book's statement "we don't have to report sentences after time conjunctions" appears to be oversimplified or ambiguous.

There is a problem with your explanation of the First sentence: you say "but the clause after the time conjunction is still true so we didn't backshift", while the question asks for cases when "after time conjunctions ... even if they aren't true anymore". So the question is: is it a bad example, and if present tense is used, must it be still true?

@DávidLaczkó I didn't agree with the book's explanation. (I think report means backshifting). A general rule cannot be made in this case. If present tense is used, it means it is a general truth.
